# Search option in product dropdown in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have successfully done the product dropdown list with the select option but I am can't include the search option inside the dropdown. I have tried some code taken from Google but failed. I am new to Laravel and I don't know how to proceed further. Please help to include the search option.

Here is the code!

Blade:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
     {{ Form::select('customer', $customers, null, ['placeholder' => 'Select A Client ID' ,'required'=> '', 'aria-required' => 'true']) }}
   </div>
   <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
    {{ Form::select('products[]', $products, null, ['multiple' => true, 'class' => 'validate multiple', 'required'=> '', 'aria-required' => 'true']) }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function add()
    {
        $title = "Add New Order";
        $customer_list = DB::table('accounts')->select('id', 'fname', 'lname')->where('account_type_id', '1')->get();
        $product_list = DB::table('products')->select('id', 'name', 'quantity')->where('status', 1)->where('show_client', 1)->where('quantity', '>', 0)->get();

        $customers = array();
        foreach ($customer_list as $customer) {
            $customers[$customer->id] = $customer->id;
        }

        $productss = array();
        foreach ($product_list as $product) {
            $productss[$product->id] = $product->name . " (" . $product->quantity . ")";
        }

        $pselect = array('value="" disabled selected' => 'Please Select Products');
        $products = $pselect + $productss;


        return view('order.add', compact('title', 'customers', 'products'));
    }
```

Route:

```
// Orders Controller
Route::get('/order', 'OrderController@manage');
Route::get('/order/add', 'OrderController@add');
Route::post('/order/add_confirm', 'OrderController@addConfirm');
Route::post('/order/add_confirmed', 'OrderController@addConfirmed');
Route::get('/order/manage/{id}', 'OrderController@manageOrder');
Route::post('/order/manage/accept', 'OrderController@manageOrderStatus');
Route::post('/order/manage/pending', 'OrderController@manageOrderStatus');
Route::post('/order/manage/cancel', 'OrderController@manageOrderStatus');
Route::post('/order/manage/fraud', 'OrderController@manageOrderStatus');
Route::post('/order/manage/delete', 'OrderController@manageOrderStatus');
Route::post('/order/save_note', 'OrderController@manageOrderNote');
Route::post('/order/emi_calculation', 'OrderController@emiCalculation');
Route::get('/order/{name}', 'OrderController@manage');
```

Comment: HTML select element is NOT searchable. What you are looking for is HTML datalist.

Comment: I don't understand. Please make it clear

Answer (score 1):

Generally, avoid using the Form Helpers ie.  {{ Form::  ...  because they make the code too complicated and long without any real advantages. Use normal simple html form tags.
To search customers, try to use DATALIST HTML element but not the select. See here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist
To populate the datalist with a default value, eg. select a customer, use its value property as shown below.
The following should work.

The web.php

```
Route::get('/order/add', 'OrderController@add'); //testing
```

The OrderController.php .  Note I have just changed your initial queries for product and customers (my customers table is called partners) a bit to match my database tables and columns but the logic is still intact.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function add()
    {
        $title = "Add New Order";
       // $customers = DB::table('accounts')->select('id', 'fname', 'lname')->where('account_type_id', '1')->get();
        $customers = DB::table('partners')/*->select('id', 'fname', 'lname')->where('account_type_id', '1')*/->get();

        //$products = DB::table('products')->select('id', 'name', 'quantity')->where('status', 1)->where('show_client', 1)->where('quantity', '>', 0)->get();
        $products = DB::table('products')/*->select('id', 'name', 'quantity')->where('status', 1)->where('show_client', 1)->where('quantity', '>', 0)*/->get();

        return view('order.add', compact('title', 'customers', 'products'));
    }
}
```

The views/add.blade.php   is as below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                    <input class="customers" list="customers" name="customer" value="Select A Customer" required>
                    <datalist id="customers">
                        @foreach($customers as $customer)
                        <option value="{{$customer->name}}" data-lname="{{$customer->name}}"
                            data-fname="{{$customer->name}}">
                        </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </datalist>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">


                <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                    <label for="products">Add the new Products</label>
                    <select multiple class="form-control" id="products" name="products[]" required>
                        <option selected disabled value="Please select Products">Please select Products</option>
                        @foreach($products as $product)
                        <option value="{{$product->name .'('. $product->quantity .')'}}"
                            data-quantity="{{$product->quantity}}">{{$product->name .'('. $product->quantity .')'}}
                        </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Results:

[image: on page load]

[image: when searching]

Comment: Getting 404 error message after replacing the code.

Comment: show your routes/web.php   file. 404 might be a problem with the routing

Comment: @AhamedAmeen has it worked? I can try it with you step by step if you need.

Comment: It's not working! Please check the routes/web.php above

Comment: @AhamedAmeen, please check my edited answer. Also remember to mark my answer as correct if it works. Thanks. Let me know in case you need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something that already exists, Select2 is a package I've used for a long time and its really good

heres the link to their page : https://select2.org

all you have to do is include CSS and JS

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

then your html should be like this :

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

and your JS:

```
// In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```